# Software raid hard, change the primary hard drive

Tags: software-raid

I have a windows server 2008, and 2 hard drive which set as RAID 1, now the primary hard drive report some error and have to change.
I have backup of major data but I have many setting on it's IIS and DNS server which I can't get backup from there.
 Is it secure that I change the primary hard drive without data lost? if I install a new hard, it will be re sync again?

Comment: Primary hard drive?

Comment: Disk 0 must replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a RAID 1 configuration, you should be able to change either drive and the array will rebuild.  You may need to initiate the rebuild from the software manager app.